# Rails 5 – Can't update single attribute with link_to, undefined method `to_sym'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to archive a `Product` by using a `link_to` in Rails 5.

In the view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= link_to product_path(product, "product[archived]" => true),
          :method => :put,
          data: { confirm: 'Sure?' } do %>
    <i class="fa fa-archive color-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But after clicking on the link my `ProductsController` throws the following error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:archived=>false}:Hash Did you mean? to_s to_yaml to_set
```

The error points to the `if @product.update(product_params)` line. Full update method is:

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  puts @product.id

  if @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Actually the offending line was a badly written validation in my `Product` model.

I had: `validates_uniqueness_of :code, :scope => [:archived => false]`, where it should have been `validates_uniqueness_of :code, conditions: -> { where.not(archived: true) }`.

In hindsight it was a silly mistake, but now I'm wondering **why it was throwing such a strange error and worse, the error was in the controller**...

Comment: What's on your routes?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma   `resources :products do
    resources :product_prices
  end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scope` attribute on the validation is expecting either a single attribute or an array of attributes from your model, something like

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :code, :scope => :archived
end
```

As it turns out, including the `:scope` option [adds a where clause during the validation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L91) which looks like `where(:archived => false)` based on my example above.

From your original code `validates_uniquesness_of :code, :scope => { :archived => false }`, this results in the scope executing `where({:archived => false} => nil)`.  You can see that the hash argument to `where` is definitely off.

Later in the stack, `ActiveRecord` is going to try to turn the key from the argument hash into a symbol with `to_sym` and look for that key as an attribute on the `Product` model.  However, the key in this case is the hash `{:archived=>false}` which does not respond to `to_sym`, and here the undefined method error gets raised.

The reason the error "appeared" in the controller is because the line `product.update(product_params)` in your controller is the beginning of the call chain that led to the bad validation being called in the model, which you have determined was the source of the error.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. I rejected the suggested edit on my question and went back to the original `validates_uniqueness_of :code, :scope => [:archived => false]`. I know this is bad syntax but I want to highlight that this is what caused the original error and strange behavior.